# Filtering on a date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter for all dates greater than the `30/6/2014`. When I set the criteria equal to the date everything works fine, but when I try to ask it only to filter everything greater the macro applies the filter but finds no records (I know there are definitely dates `> 30/6/14` in my data set.

I've checked all the variables and they are definitely fine because, as I say, when I set the criteria equal to `30/6/14` the correct results are displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rowcount5, columncount1)).AutoFilter Field:=matchfunction3, Criteria1:=">30/06/2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoFilter can easily be confused by date formats.  With data like:

[image]

Running this:

```
Sub DateFilter()
With Range("A1:A24")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & CStr(DateSerial(2015, 3, 20)), Operator:=xlAnd
End With
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

By using the *DateSerial()* function, any confusion is avoided.